# What time does the daily quest timer reset?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

What time does the daily quest timer reset? I play on the US WildHammer realm, if that matters. Its a central time zone server.

Comment: I think it depends on the local realm time, your time zone is irrelevant.

Comment: The game is on central time zone. It's a realm at the Chicago data center.

Comment: Does game time always correlate to the data center location?  I thought they just divvied up the game timezones to provide some options.

Comment: @NickT - Data Centers and Battle Groups can both have servers that are using one to four different time zones. Here is a link to [Wowpedia](http://www.wowpedia.org/US_realm_list_by_datacenter) that shows it all. It shame you didn't ask this as a real question here on Gaming SE. I could have made a quick 15 points.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's generally 3 AM or 4 AM server time, based on whether Daylight Saving Time is in effect, but the exact time the server resets depends on the server: you can find out the exact time by logging into the game and hovering your cursor over the quest count in the top-left corner of the quest log.

Comment: Correct. Reference: http://www.wowwiki.com/Daily_quest

Comment: Since about Legion prelaunch, this is no longer correct. See Presto's answer.

Answer (score 7):

Per Blizzard:

... reset timers for recurring in-game activities such as daily/weekly quests and raid/dungeon lockouts will be updated to a single unified lockout time of 15:00:00 UTC (8 a.m. PDT / 1 a.m. AEST) for all North American, Latin American, and Oceanic realms. -- as of July 01, 2016.

source: http://us.battle.net/forums/en/wow/topic/20745655899

Answer (score -3):

The daily quest reset is set per server and never changes.

> The exact reset hour depends on the
>   realm, but it never changes, is chosen
>   to be in the early morning, and will
>   not coincide with the instance reset.

from http://wowpedia.org/Daily_quest#Restrictions

Comment: Based on the comment on your latest edit, you've misinterpreted my answer and what "never changes" refers to. When Daylight Saving Time is in effect, timezones shift by one hour: 3 AM becomes 4 AM. So while the absolute time the server resets never changes, the local time of the player will change depending on whether DST is in effect, and the server time displayed to the user does, in fact, honor DST rules. It's no different than if the player moved from one timezone to another.